# How to open the regular pop-up menu with control dot when PostSharp is installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, postsharp

A lot of times when I want to rename a variable, I use the Control-Dot shortcut to pull up the popup menu where I can let Visual Studio do it for me.  However, with PostSharp installed it takes over the shortcut to make its own menu pop up and the only way I know to get the default one to come up is to move my mouse over the tiny area at the end of the word which isn't a big deal but kind of annoying.

Does anyone know how I can make it go back to pulling up the regular menu with the shortcut since I really never use the PostSharp one anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a defect of Visual Studio because PostSharp does not override any shortcut but instead implements a smart tag provider and the rest is managed by VS. Yet I agree this is annoying. You can disable PostSharp smart tags from the menu PostSharp / Options.

Comment: Thanks Gael.  I actually really wish it would work the other way around... that it would pull up the regular menu on the shortcut, but still show the little PostSharp underline that you could hover the mouse over to open up.  But if I can't have it that way then I gotta go with the default popup cause I just use it way more.

Comment: Yeah this is how VS works unfortunately. We're just implementing IViewTaggerProvider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.iviewtaggerprovider(v=vs.110).aspx